Install plugins to an nvim-only package folder inside ~/.vim?
I want to try out nvim, but I don't want to break my vim configuration. I have my vim config in ~/.vim and I have an %LocalAppData%\nvim\init.lua that sources my vimrc and this block in my vimrc get nvim to load all my vimscript:
if has('win32') || has('nvim')
    set runtimepath^=$HOME/.vim
    set runtimepath+=$HOME/.vim/after
endif
if has('nvim')
    " :help nvim-from-vim said to do this
    let &packpath = &runtimepath
endif

So far so good.
I want to install some nvim plugins (lspconfig, mason) but don't want them loaded in vim (where I use pathogen). I could create a blacklist, but then I'd have to remember that every time I install one. An nvim-only location for plugins seems more convenient. I'd like to try to use the built-in package system, but I don't understand what to add to packpath to make that happen.
How can I set packpath to add ~/.vim/nvim as a folder for plugins? (So a plugin might have the path ~/.vim/nvim/lspconfig/plugin/lspconfig.lua.)


How can I set packpath to add ~/.vim/nvim as a folder for plugins?

You can do :set packpath^=~/.vim/nvim to add it to the front of the packpath.
The advice to copy &runtimepath to &packpath doesn't make much sense to me, though, unless Neovim uses packpath very differently from Vim: its docs are a bit unclear:
    "start" packages will also be searched (runtime-search-path) for
    runtime files after these, though such packages are not explicitly
    reported in &runtimepath. But "opt" packages are explicitly added to
    &runtimepath by :packadd.

and
Nvim searches for :runtime files in:
    1. all paths in 'runtimepath'
    2. all "pack/*/start/*" dirs
Note that the "pack/*/start/*" paths are not explicitly included in
'runtimepath', so they will not be reported by ":set rtp" or "echo &rtp".
Scripts can use nvim_list_runtime_paths() to list all used directories, and
nvim_get_runtime_file() to query for specific files or sub-folders within
the runtime path. Example:

Anyway, if you didn't need that, you could simply use Neovim's default packpath (which is… its runtimepath?) to install your plugins.

I've realized nvim suggests &packpath = &runtimepath because ~/.vim is not in runtimepath! Instead it uses $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim which I guess is usually ~/.nvim.

set packpath^=~/.vim/nvim solves my problem. It's not quite what I was looking for because packages require a bunch of intermediate paths: ~/.vim/nvim/pack/core/start/lspconfig/plugin/lspconfig.lua (where core is arbitrary). but I think that's a requirement of packages.

@idbrii for that, see :help packages: that's true in general
